# xslt problem issue

Tags: xml, vb.net, xslt

hi all i m having one xml like bellow

```
<NewDataSet>
    <Table>
        <CTD_REC_TYPE_ID>5</CTD_REC_TYPE_ID> 
        <CTD_BEN_INS_ID>0048201515</CTD_BEN_INS_ID> 
        <CTD_CURR_CODE>2</CTD_CURR_CODE> 
        <CTD_ORD_CUST_ACT>CACC</CTD_ORD_CUST_ACT> 
        <CTD_CTD_PKG_ID>6</CTD_CTD_PKG_ID> 
    </Table>
    <Table>
        <CTD_REC_TYPE_ID>5</CTD_REC_TYPE_ID> 
        <CTD_BEN_INS_ID>004820101</CTD_BEN_INS_ID> 
        <CTD_CURR_CODE>2</CTD_CURR_CODE> 
        <CTD_ORD_CUST_ACT>CACC</CTD_ORD_CUST_ACT> 
        <CTD_CTD_PKG_ID>6</CTD_CTD_PKG_ID> 
    </Table>
    <Table>
        <CTD_REC_TYPE_ID>5</CTD_REC_TYPE_ID> 
        <CTD_BEN_INS_ID>004820101</CTD_BEN_INS_ID> 
        <CTD_CURR_CODE>2</CTD_CURR_CODE> 
        <CTD_ORD_CUST_ACT>CACC</CTD_ORD_CUST_ACT> 
        <CTD_CTD_PKG_ID>3</CTD_CTD_PKG_ID> 
    </Table>
</NewDataSet>
```

in the above xml every table  have to concentrate `<CTD_CTD_PKG_ID>3</CTD_CTD_PKG_ID>` (package id ) as if above example we are having three table in that xml when coming to pkg id 6,6,3   six was repeated two time for that i have concatenate that two similar table and make as one csv file and rest other pkg id for 3 we have prepare seperate csv file so that we need to write xslt  can any one help me please ....asap

Comment: it would help if you could add your expected output to the question.

Comment: You ask a lot of XSLT questions lately and they are still poorly formulated. Please put some effort.

Comment: output like:                                                                    5,0048201515,2,cacc,6                                                  5,004820101,2,cacc,6                                              these records should generate as one csv file                        rest of one record 5,004820101,2,cacc,3 in another csv file

Comment: For multiple outputs you need XSLT 2.0, or some extension from your XSLT processor. Otherwise you could run the transformation multiple times as in @Filburt answer.

Comment: actually guys ... my goal is to send a parameter value is nothing but package id  to xsl stylesheet then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need `n` different output files you will need to run your transformation `n` times, each time with the desired `<CTD_CTD_PKG_ID>` value as  a filter parameter.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" indent="no" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

    <!-- sample value hardcoded here for demonstration -->
    <xsl:param name="filterid" select="3" />

    <!--
        for implementation just declare param
        <xsl:param name="filterid" />
    -->

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="NewDataSet">
        <xsl:for-each select="Table[CTD_CTD_PKG_ID = $filterid]">
            <xsl:text/><xsl:value-of select="./CTD_REC_TYPE_ID"/>;<xsl:text/>
            <xsl:text/><xsl:value-of select="./CTD_BEN_INS_ID"/>;<xsl:text/>
            <xsl:text/><xsl:value-of select="./CTD_CURR_CODE"/>;<xsl:text/>
            <xsl:text/><xsl:value-of select="./CTD_ORD_CUST_ACT"/>;<xsl:text/>
            <xsl:text/><xsl:value-of select="./CTD_CTD_PKG_ID"/><xsl:text/>
            <xsl:text>&#13;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

How you go about to pass the param value for `filterid` depends on the transformation engine you are using.

If using this Xslt on the sample Xml data you will receive

```
5;004820101;2;CACC;3
```

as your result.

If you set `<xsl:param name="filterid" select="6" />` you will receive

```
5;0048201515;2;CACC;6
5;004820101;2;CACC;6
```

See [XslCompiledTransform.Transform with XsltArgumentList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms163439.aspx) for reference on how to submit a parameter to a Xslt using the .NET framework.

Comment: @filburt ..i m not getting output with this xslt can you explain briefly

Comment: @praveen If you don't get any output your Xml is different from the sample you provided in your post. See my updated answer on how to submit a param value to a xslt stylesheet.

Comment: @filburt thnx a lot getting xactly result ..but i m struggling with how to pass variable to xslt in vb.net window form

Comment: @praveen Did you try out the VB.Net code sample on the MSDN reference I linked?

Comment: @filburt...i have tried but in xslt it was saying that children could not be evaluvated ..!!! this is wen we are dynamically passing parameters into xsl, by your xample if  we hot coded but putting one value means ex:select='6' means output ws coming exactly

Comment: @praveen From the other questions you're asking I'm guessing you're trying to hand code a solution that could be easier done by using a out-of-the-box EAI product. Take a look at [BlueIntegrator](http://www.blueintegrator.com) (free) or [BizTalk](http://www.microsoft.com/biztalk/en/us/default.aspx) (expensive) - they will offer everything you'll need.

Comment: @filbert thanks a lot your code was very use full to me ... how do we can use for-each instead of if condition

Comment: @praveen See my updated answer with an example using `for-each` instead of `if` template.